# How do I Apply a Transfer Function Filter in R?

Tags: r, time-series

Say I have a set of time-series data `y[t],` and I want to apply an operator `H(B) = (1 - \phi*B)/(1 + \theta*B)` to it, where `phi` and `theta` are constants and `B` is the lag operator. How can I do this in R? The filter command only allows me to apply the numerator, not the denominator.

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example, showing what you have tried till now?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I can use filter(y, c(1,-phi)) to apply (1-\phi B)y_t = y_t - \phi y_{t-1}, but not the inverse of the lag operator. So how can I do (1/(1-\phi B))y_t? I need this because I have to apply certain coefficients from an SARIMA estimation to my time-series data y_t. Something like this, except mine is SARIMA so I can't use the forecast library function: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43370/filtering-using-arma-model-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `method` argument for the `filter` function.

Apply the `filter` function twice using `method = "convolution"` and `method = "recursive"` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Taylor expansion of the denominator gives the series `1/(1+x) = 1-x+x^2-x^3+...`. So in case `\theta<1` you get a proper way to approximate to a desired order in `\theta`. Hope this helps.

Disclaimer: There probably are better ways. I am not a time series expert.